# How do I use a Select Statement as the Source in a T-SQL Merge Update

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, merge

OK, My first question on here.

I am a novice with T-SQL and MSSQL Server, so be patient with me.

I've been playing around with the MERGE command a little and have used it to help synchronize some tables in a database and it's worked well so far.

My Question is this.  I have a table with production data coming in daily, and part of the data includes the NetWeight of individual cases of products being produced.

I figured out a quick Select Query that will go through the production data and calculate the Average Weight of boxes based on Product Code.

```
select ProductCode, AVG(NetWeight) FROM dbo.Production
Group By ProductCode
Order by ProductCode
```

In my ProductMaster table, I have a column for AverageWeight.

What I want to do is use my Select Query as the Source of a Merge Command that I could use to Update the AverageWeight column in my ProductMaster table.

Once working, I'd turn it into a Stored Procedure and schedule it to run daily so the ProductMaster table is automatically updated when new products have been run in the plant, and it will keep the average case weights up to date.

My understanding is you can use a Select Query as the source for Merge, but haven't found good examples of how it works.
Thanks

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. I don't understand what you are trying to do here. Perhaps sharing the table structure, some data and desired output would help. Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 4):

Assuming ProductCode is the like column:

```
alter table ProductMasteradd AverageWeight number

merge into ProductMaster t
using(
     select 
        ProductCode
      , AverageWeight = AVG(NetWeight)
     from dbo.Production
     group By ProductCode
     order by ProductCode
    )s
on t.ProductCode = s.ProductCode
when matched then update
set t.AverageWeight  = s.AverageWeight;
```

Note, when using merge you must end the statement with ";", or you will receive an error.